# How to add kerning to the word

Tags: xetex, kerning

On my `Lbend` command I need more space between a second word letters. How to get more space between letters?

`\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}` doesn't want to work with  `\TU/lmtt/bx/n/24.88` font and I get warning `fontspec Warning: \addfontfeature(s) ignored`.

```
%%MWE
\documentclass[xetex,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{Latin Modern Roman}

\newlength{\tmpw}\newlength{\tmph}
\newcommand{\Lbend}[2]{\settowidth{\tmpw}{#1}\settoheight{\tmph}{#1}%
\smash{#1{\hspace{-1.02\tmpw}\raisebox{-0.55ex}{\rule{.05\tmph}{0.8ex}\rule{.7\tmpw}{.05\tmph}}}%
\raisebox{-0.80ex}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}\bfseries #2}}}%

\begin{document}
{\ttfamily \bfseries\Huge{\Lbend{slackware}{\small linux}}}\\

{\ttfamily \Large{\Lbend{testtest}{\tiny test}}}\\

\end{document}
%%EOF
```

[image: logo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enable letterspacing through fontspec (e.g. with `\addfontfeature`), then you have to load the affected font through fontspec. In this case you use `\ttfamily`, so you need the monospace font (`\setmonofont`). The default monospace font is `Latin Modern Mono Light`.

Based on your `\defaultfont` line I will assume that on your system Latin Modern is available as a system font. (BTW That should probably be `\setmainfont` instead, otherwise the line isn't doing anything.)

```
\documentclass[xetex,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} % Not necessary for this, but I guess that's what you tried to do woth the \defaultfont line?
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Light} % Load Latin Modern's monospace font.

\newlength{\tmpw}\newlength{\tmph}
\newcommand{\Lbend}[2]{\settowidth{\tmpw}{#1}\settoheight{\tmph}{#1}%
\smash{#1{\hspace{-1.02\tmpw}\raisebox{-0.55ex}{\rule{.05\tmph}{0.8ex}\rule{.7\tmpw}{.05\tmph}}}%
\raisebox{-0.80ex}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}\bfseries #2}}}%

\begin{document}
\expandafter\show\the\font
{\ttfamily \bfseries\Huge{\Lbend{slackware}{\small linux}}}\\

{\ttfamily \Large{\Lbend{testtest}{\tiny test}}}\\

\end{document}
```

[image]